# I can't figure out how to ccreate a complex latex figure with lots of formulas

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

For practice, I am trying to emulate a figure from a paper I found. It looks like this:

[image: I want it to look like this]

Right now, what I have looks like this:

[image]

I think I managed to get the two blocks on the top right, using tables. The first column is the name, the second column is the variable name, the third column is the ::== and the last column is the cases.

However, I don't know how to do everything else.

- How do I add the "consistency", "expression typing", etc headers?
- How do I add the little boxes on the same line as the headers but aligned to the right?
- How do I get the formulas on the consistency row to not look all smushed together?
- How do I get my table to not overflow the margins like it is right now?

Here is my current Latex code:

```
\newcommand{\LABELS}{
\begin{tabular}{l l c l}
Blame labels & $\ell$ \\
Base types   & $B$ & $::=$ & \<int> $|$ \<bool> \\
Types        & $T$ & $::=$ & $B$ $|$ $T -> T$ $|$ $\star$
\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\VALUES}{
\begin{tabular}{l l c l}
Constants
  & $k$ & $::=$
  & \<true> $|$ \<false> $|$ 0 $|$ $\dots$ \\

Expressions
  & $e$ &  ::= 
  & $k$ $|$ $x$ $|$ $\lambda x:T.e$ $|$ $(e\;e)^\ell$ \\

\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\RULES}{
\inference*{ \\  }{ \star \sim T }

\inference*{ \\  }{ T \sim \star }

\inference*{ A \sim B \\  }{ $\ldots$ }

}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\LABELS & \VALUES \\
\RULES
\end{tabular}   
\end{figure}
```

The `\inference` macros and the `\<...>` macros come from the `semantic` package. In any case, what I'm really trying to figure out here is the overall layout - the formulas themselves don't matter as much.

Comment: What is the logic of the page layout in the original example? Are the locations of these expressions meaningful in some way or are you just reproducing it as an exercise?

Comment: I'm reproducing it as an excercise. If only pdfs had view-latex-source functionality...

Comment: So, `amsmath` provides `\boxed{}` which allows you to box equations, note that `\boxed{}` requires you to be in math mode. Also, you can use `\phantom{}` to produce a blank box the same size as whatever is in the brackets; you could use that to separate the fractions but it is kinda hackish.

Comment: For the sequent-type proofs, take a look at http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/ for a range of options. `prftree` and `ebproof` are newer packages which may not be listed there yet but are available from CTAN and in the current version of TeX Live, at least.